# PHP framework for rich client (Javascript)

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, soa

I am a web developer, and I prefer to use a rich-client type of web apps. 
So the server sends a data (JSON, XML) to the client, rather than an html.
While at the client side I have a jQuery full-featured app with MVC.
Here is the question: what framework should I use on server side? While I don't need any MVC on server anymore, but want it to be OOP well-structured, instead of plain PHP (as I'm using it now).

Maybe in this case it would be good to use something SOA-oriented? I'm not in touch with it yet, but it seems to fit my needs. Please enlight me.

And any other suggestions about this kind of architecture are welcome.

Thanks.

Comment: Why wouldn't you have no need for MVC? I'm not saying you need to do MVC perse, but if you say you don't need it now because it is a rich client your statement is wrong.

Comment: It may be wrong, I'm confused with it actually. The thing is that there is no need for server to update view anymore -- it's all done on the client-side. All the server does is handeling data for the client. No html page construction with PHP -- the most annoying thing for me in thin-client approach. JS/HTML5 takes care of all the UI stuff.

Comment: The actual data (no matter what form) is still coming from the backend (PHP in your case), so you still have to separate presentation and business logic.

Comment: For this a micro-framework like Fat Free could be a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Symfony2](http://symfony.com/) may fit to your requirements. It's an MVC framework **but you don't have to use this feature**. It is actively maintain and has a strong community.

Comment: That is exactly what I was looking for! Thank you Florent